# HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests by python geopy

Tags: python, python-requests, geopy, http-status-code-429

I have a problem that I am not sure how to solve. I want to iterate through a file where I want to convert the coordinates to the geolocation address.The code works fine but after it iteretes through a certain number of lines in the file the problem occurs.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from shapely.wkt import loads as load_wkt
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import io
import re
import ast
import time

geolocator = Nominatim()

with io.open('sample_test2.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f, io.open('sample_test3.txt', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as g:
        for line in f:
                m = re.sub(r'(70[0-9]+,).*', r'\1', line.rstrip())
                z = re.sub(r'.*POINT \([0-9]+.[0-9]+ -[0-9]+.[0-9]+\)(.*)', r'\1', line.rstrip())
                c = re.sub(r'.*POINT \(([0-9]+.[0-9]+) (-[0-9]+.[0-9]+)\).*', r'"\1, \2"', line.rstrip())
                k = ast.literal_eval(c)
                location = geolocator.reverse(k, timeout=60)
                h = location.address
                j = re.sub(r'.*, ([^,]+, [^,]+), [0-9]+, United.*', r'\1', h.rstrip())
                print (m, j, z, file = g)
f.close()
g.close()
```

Now I read from some other questions that I should use `time.sleep()`. Now I wanted to put it before the `print`. The first time I run my code (without `time.sleep()`) it came to around 1800 lines that he converted before getting this error:

```
    raise GeocoderServiceError(message)
geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

But now with or without the `time.sleep()` it doesn't even do the first line it just breaks from the beginning with the error. Any idea what to do?

Comment: http://www.jackmaney.com/2015/01/09/geocoding-rate-limited-queue/

Comment: What is the differnece between this code and that I put a time.sleep(0.1)like I read the code it limits it at 10 per second, with time.sleep(0.1) I do the same or?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573613/8884513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like whatever webservice you are using has blocked you, most likely via your IP address. Wait for a while and then make sure that you are being "friendly" to the service, e.g., by inserting those sleeps.

Comment: Is there any way how to check what is the maximum I can convert per secund,minute,hour,day..???

Comment: They will probably have it in their documentation somewhere.