# How get latitude and longitude through address without too many requests error in python

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

I have a database contains 5000 building approx, I want to locate them through its address, so I use GeoPy like this:

```
def getLalo(address):
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    if location == None:
        return [0,0]
    return [location.latitude,location.longitude]

bmk['latitude'], bmk['longitude']= bmk.apply(lambda row: getLalo(row['full_address']), axis=1)
```

However, seems like I got `GeocoderServiceError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests`

How do I avoid this? thx!

Comment: In your function, you can try adding `sleep(time_you_want)` to avoid being locked out.

Comment: could you please just give me an example? thx

Comment: @stat0619 from time import sleep
sleep(0.1) # Time in seconds.

Comment: @Darnell Martin is 0.1s enough? you mean just add time.sleep(0.1) in function getLalo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests by python geopy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031705/http-error-429-too-many-requests-by-python-geopy)

Answer (score 0):

When you send requests in short of time, 
rate-limiting must be taken into account.

You will receive: 
Too Many Requests 429 HTTP error or timing out.

Try with RateLimiter

```
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)
```

reference
https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.16.0/#usage-with-pandas