# bulk geolocate location strings by countries

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopy, nominatim

I have a large dataset of addresses (a couple of millions) as strings that needs to be mapped to countries.

I've looked into using [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/) and nominatim locally but seems that downloading and loading the whole planet database of open street map is an overkill for this specially that I only need to do this once.

Is there a way to get a local **subset** of open street maps that would still be able to work with nominatim to get this task done ?

Comment: Or you could query Nominatim directly. Geopy has RateLimiter module, which helps to deal with rate limiting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573613/8884513

Comment: @KostyaEsmukov yeah but that would take months to run if I stuck with the `1 request per second`