# convert county state names to coordinates

Tags: python, geopy

I want to convert county state name to coordinates.

county:

```
fips    state_fips  county_fips state   county
1000    1   0   Alabama Alabama
1005    1   5   Alabama Barbour County
1007    1   7   Alabama Bibb County
1009    1   9   Alabama Blount County
1011    1   11  Alabama Bullock County
6085    6   85  California  Santa Clara County
6089    6   89  California  Shasta County
6091    6   91  California  Sierra County
32021   32  21  Nevada  Mineral County
32023   32  23  Nevada  Nye County
32027   32  27  Nevada  Pershing County
32029   32  29  Nevada  Storey County
```

I want to use python geopy package.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
geolocator = Nominatim()
county['coord'] = county['county'].apply(geolocator.geocode)
```

I got the error:

```
socket.timeout: timed out
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out
```

How should I fix it? thanks

Comment: above code works for me, can you please sample of your data frame how it's structured.

Comment: fips  state_fips  county_fips    state          county  
0  1000           1            0  Alabama         Alabama  
1  1001           1            1  Alabama  Autauga County  
2  1003           1            3  Alabama  Baldwin County   .It is same as that in the question. So strange.

Comment: i am getting output like below,

0    (Alabama, United States of America, (33.258881...
1    (Barbour County, Alabama, United States of Ame...
2    (Bibb County, Georgia, United States of Americ...
Name: coord, dtype: object

Comment: My python3 is up to date. And I have tried to restart python and do it again. Have no idea why different computer could give different output.

Comment: The only reason which I can think of is, representation of your data frame object.

Comment: I copy the first 5 observations of the county dataset (which is large) to another dataframe for test. When I add .copy(), I don't see the error any more. However, I have a new error: geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out. Do you know the reason?

Comment: that means you reached a "time out" in the nominatim server. initialize Nominatim with a higher timeout (>1)
try this:
geolocator=Nominatim(timeout=3)

Comment: My real dataset county has several thousands of observations, how should I do it?

Comment: Nominatim Usage Policy [restricts the query rate to 1 rps](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/). If that's too low, you should use another service (or provision your own local instance of Nominatim). If that's enough, then simply add ```sleep(1)``` call between the queries.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031705/http-error-429-too-many-requests-by-python-geopy

Comment: county['coord'] = county['county'].apply(geolocator.geocode) would do all the locations in the column "county". where should I add sleep(1) in the command?

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

geolocator = Nominatim()

def geocode_with_sleep(query):
    sleep(1)
    return geolocator.geocode(query)

county['coord'] = county['county'].apply(geocode_with_sleep)
```

Another way is described in http://www.jackmaney.com/2015/01/09/geocoding-rate-limited-queue/

Answer (score 0):

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

def get_coordinates(place_name):
  geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geo_locator")  
  location = geolocator.geocode(place_name)        
  if location:                                     
    return location.latitude, location.longitude   
  else:
    return None, None
```

There's a more detailed tutorial here: https://medium.com/python-in-plain-english/how-to-use-geocoding-libraries-to-visualise-pakistans-conflict-data-f16b4a52853c